# Anaconda3 Python interpreter doesn't printing colors

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I'm using the Anaconda3 Python interpreter in VS Code, this code should print some red text and it works only in the VS Code terminal with CMD as the default terminal. trying on any other terminal (even externals terminals), I get the following print:

```
>>> print("\033[31mRED\033[0;0m")
←[31mRED←[0;0m
```

Comment: What precisely is your question?

Comment: How to print colors on anaconda? It seems to work normally in "regular" python...

Comment: ANSI codes work in `Jupyter notebook`; Idn if they work in the interactive interpreter.

Comment: It seems to work with ```colorama.init()```.

Comment: You might be right. I tested 5 libraries and no one worked.